# Custom css is not reflecting on my webpage. Bootstrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to the Bootstrap world and I am following an online class to learn Bootstrap.

From there I learnt that I can have custom CSS classes that I can use in my webpage.

So I have created a folder called `my project folder` and I have linked the path in head of my page.

```
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" herf="css/styles.css">
```

But now the CSS effects sre not reflected in the webpage

```
.footer{
    background-color: #D1C4E9;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

I have used sublime as an editor, linux(ubuntu20)

Comment: check out your console,is there any error saying 'file not found' or sth else

Comment: error: Unable to save ~/Documents/Bootstrap4/conFusion/customCss/styles.css
Error: No such file or directory

Comment: Where do you have your style.css file ,in css folder or customCss folder?

Comment: Because the priority of order of the css link is important. last link is more priority than top.

Comment: css i have changed it now ...problem is somthing else

Comment: See EDIT 1.1 in regards to local pathing and CDN's

Comment: do you see your custom style at all when you inspect the element using the browser's dev tools? probably you have a less specific selector and the style is overriden by bootstrap

Comment: Are you trying to get bootstrap working locally without the CDN links? is that what you want to do. You downloaded the files and trying to link them in the HTML?

Comment: @AhmadDalao yep but my custon css changes are not reflecting on my web page    ... but everthing is working fine

Comment: So your bootstrap CSS is working just fine and only your `styles.css` not working is that right? In that cause can you provide a snippet we should be able to help.

Comment: @AhmadDalao my please check my repo yahsashay/conFusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your CSS link. the word `href` is spelled wrong. that's why your CSS can not be detected.

Wrong:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" herf="css/styles.css">
```

Right:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: i need sleep ...sry

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 1.1** This is the Bootstrap get started template not the one you linked.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's a blank slate template, open for you imagination. Try looking at the component section on the Bootstrap website @ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/. Adding component in between the `body` tag will get you started.

Bootstrap uses CDN's Content Delivery Network to load stylesheets and javascript files. CDN's have minimize delays in loading web page content by reducing the physical distance between the server and the user. CDN's don't use local path and have better performances most of the time.

It's common and best practice to use CDN's with a local fallback in case the CDN connection fails. **In your case, your problem is probably coming from your local url path. If you don't want to use CDN's make sure your local pathing is right.**

Comment: i just want to confirm  ....you mean to say every bootstrap version have its own started template i amusing a differnt one

Comment: its bootstrap4.0.0 started template ...... but the version of bootstrap i am using is latest

Comment: check out the bbotstrap documentation

Comment: Bootstrap template are generic and are juste a base to start your project. The Bootstrap version will affect components, not the template. The latest stable current Bootstrap version is 4.5.2.

Comment: @amarinediary i have downloaded everthing jquery popper.js bootstrap4   the latest version my pathing is correct ...i have linked correctly my styles.css folder

Comment: Let's back up a bit then, [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63980308/edit) your post with more informations regarding your problem, i'm not sure I understand. Try to be specific, what are you trying to do, what is happening, give as much information as you can. Maybe take a look on how to ask a question by taking the [Stackoverflow tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).